# two iterations on dispatchKeyEvent

Tags: java

I'm using a KeyEventDispatcher to capture when someone presses a key.

Right now I'm using a switch to print a message:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent( KeyEvent e ) {

    if ( e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED ){

    switch ( e.getKeyChar() ) {
    case '\n':
        System.out.println( "Equals" );
        break;
    case '+':
        System.out.println( "Addition" );
        break;
    case '-':
        System.out.println( "Subtraction" );
        break;
    case '/':
        System.out.println( "Division" );
        break;
    case '*':
        System.out.println( "Multiplication" );
        break;
    case '1':
        System.out.println( "1" );
        break;
    case '2':
        System.out.println( "2" );
        break;
    case '3':
        System.out.println( "3" );
        break;
    case '4':
        System.out.println( "4" );
        break;
    case '5':
        System.out.println( "5" );
        break;
    case '6':
        System.out.println( "6" );
        break;
    case '7':
        System.out.println( "7" );
        break;
    case '8':
        System.out.println( "8" );
        break;
    case '9':
        System.out.println( "9" );
        break;
    case 'c':
    case '':
        System.out.println( "Clear" );
        break;
    case 'a':
        System.out.println( "Clear Everything" );
        break;
    default:
        break;
```

I get two print lines for the output tho. For example, when I press 9, the output is as follows:

> 9
>   
>   9

When I step into, this runs twice:

```
        java.util.List<KeyEventDispatcher> dispatchers = getKeyEventDispatchers();
    if (dispatchers != null) {
        for (java.util.Iterator<KeyEventDispatcher> iter = dispatchers.iterator();
             iter.hasNext(); )
         {
             if (iter.next().
                 dispatchKeyEvent(ke))
             {
                 return true;
             }
         }
    }
    return dispatchKeyEvent(ke);
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? If I take the switch statement out of the if statement, i get 6 print lines. I can't figure it out!

Comment: KEY_PRESSED will be fired multiple times depending on how long user presses key and OS keyboard repeat setting... Are you sure you don't want KEY_TYPED instead?

Comment: Here is the full project @ github. Perhaps there is a problem with how I register? Sorry, the code is a bit wonky.

Answer (score 2):

For every physical key typed on the keyboard the following events will occur

- One or more KEY_PRESSED events depending on how long the key is held
- One KEY_RELEASED event
- One KEY_TYPED event - this is a synthetic event made as a result of a press and a release event.

It is likely you need to use KEY_TYPED instead. Another possibility is you've registered the listener twice.

Comment: Hmm. This makes sense to me. It still presents two of each number I press for some reason. I do not have the listener registered twice but I do have an actionlistener. There wouldn't be a conflict there would there be?